# How to: Run Liferay based Web portals in IBM Bluemix

Tags: liferay, licensing, ibm-cloud

I am running some Liferay applications in my organization using the liferay enterprise edition. How can I move these applications to IBM Blumix. If it is possible how are the liferay enterprise licenses managed in Bluemix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Websphere Full/Liberty profile as Application Server for Liferay**

according to what I found on Liferay documentation/user guide, Liferay is  supported on Websphere 8.5 and this guide

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-websphere-8-5-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15--3

explain how to proceed.

In the same guide I find that

> Please also note that the WebSphere Application Liberty Profile is not supported by Liferay.

so, to give a complete answer to what you are looking for:

- you cannot make Liferay running on a Bluemix Liberty Runtime (because of the missing support for Liberty WAS profile)
- you could create a Bluemix Docker container or Bluemix Virtual Machine running Websphere 8.5 Full Profile and deploy Liferay on it

About Docker container, you could find some guides on the network, one of them is the following
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/devTips/entry/running_websphere_on_docker_container?lang=en

About Bluemix VM, being an openStack VM I suppose you should go on in the same way of installing WebSphere on a local VM.

**Tomcat as Application Server for Liferay**

Liferay is fully supported on Tomcat Application Server, which is available on Bluemix Cloud Saas on the Bluemix Runtime using the following buildpack **java_buildpack** with

```
cf push [app-name] -b java_buildpack
```

This buildpack provides openJDK and Tomcat as Application server

Obviously creating a Bluemix Docker Container or a VM running Tomcat as Application Server will allow to deploy Liferay on this Application Server as usual.